# What is the best way to import folder of images in next js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

What is the best way to import folder of images in next js?

I'm using `require.context` but it renders images 2 times.

For example, if I have 100 photos, it renders 200 !

```
const imagesListAllWork = require.context(
  "../../public/images/gallery/logo/",
  false,
  /\.(png|jpeg|svg|jpg)$/

const imagesListAllWork = imageAllWork
    .keys()
    .map((image, index) => imageAllWork(image));
```